# What is the difference between f and F

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code, the const are defined using two different ways.

```
     const float KS = 0.001F;
     const float WW = 0.001f;
```

Is there any difference between F and f?

**Revision 1:**
If both are same then why both cases are allowed ?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason why both cases shouldn't be allowed?

Comment: It may create confusion. As string and String are also same. I was just wondering why both are allowed. Microsoft can restrict developer to use only a single one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nope, no difference between `f` and `F` in this case. It's the special suffix for `float` literals, either works fine.

With the `long` literals, there's stylistic difference: `l` (lowercase) looks a lot like `1` (the number one). It's recommended to use capital `L` for `long` literals.

#### References

- [MSDN/C# Programmer's Reference/float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28VS.71%29.aspx)

  > By default, a real numeric literal on the right-hand side of the assignment operator is treated as `double`. Therefore, to initialize a float variable use the suffix `f` or `F`.
- [MSDN/C# Programmer's Reference/long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

  > You can also use the lowercase letter `"l"` as a suffix. However, this generates a compiler warning because the letter `"l"` is easily confused with the digit `"1"`. Use `"L"` for clarity.

Comment: If both are same then why both cases are allowed ?

Comment: It may create confusion. As string and String are also same. I was just wondering why both are allowed. Microsoft can restrict developer to use only a single one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the case :) Functionality wise, no. Its the same as `String` and `string`.

Comment: If both are same then why both cases are allowed ?

Comment: It is just an alias. I tend to use it to differ between referring to an object or the type itself i.e if I am using a static method of string I would always do `String.IsNullOrEmpty` never `string.IsNullOrEmpty` purely my own style as I think it looks neater. On the other hand I don't tend to do `String str = "test"` I always do `string str = "test"`. It may also be for people porting from Java as the case was always `String`.